# Retrieving text from a child node of a li

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to retrieve the text of an a element of li element that I created via javascript. Here is the code I used to create:

```
function myFunction(search) {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('delegateNameInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("nameList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    data = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var lineItem = document.createElement("li");
        lineItem.setAttribute('onClick', 'setName(this)');
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test2"));
        lineItem.appendChild(link);
        ul.appendChild(lineItem);
    }
}
```

How would I get the text from the a element?

Comment: It looks like you're creating multiple `<li>` elements each with their own child `<a>` element. Which `<a>` text are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: If you add an id to the element you want to retrieve text from like this: `link.id = "link";` then you can retrieve the text like this: `document.getElementById("link").innerHTML`. For example, if you had set the text to "test2" like this `link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test2"));` then you would be able to retrieve "test2" from `innerHTML`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: This is just my test code, I'm a bit confused, you said if I created it like this and then that is how I did create it. I need to get the text from the child <a> on the clicked one. So I would do a function such as function select(this) and then I should be able to get the innerHTML?

Comment: I was just giving an example of the string that you could retrieve using innerHTML based on that line that you wrote. Sorry for the confusion. So wait - do you want to write a function that will be called when the user clicks on a link, and then the function retrieves the text of the link that was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

The way it's written, the anchor element is the first child of the LI element created, and is pointed to by the `firstChild` property of the LI element.

Alternatively you could locate the A element as the first entry in the `children` property of the LI node in the DOM.

For the purposes of this demo I've set the text within list items to different data array entries, declared `data`, and ignored unused variables `input, filter` and `li`:

```js
"use strict";
function myFunction(search) {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, data;
    input = document.getElementById('delegateNameInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("nameList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    data = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var lineItem = document.createElement("li");
        lineItem.setAttribute('onClick', 'setName(this)');
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));
        lineItem.appendChild(link);
        ul.appendChild(lineItem);
    }
}

function setName( lineItem) {
    console.log("setName>lineItem>Anchor>link text = '" + lineItem.firstChild.textContent + "'");
    console.log("(using children: '" + lineItem.children[0].textContent + "')");
}

myFunction(null);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="delegateNameInput" placeholder="delegateNameInput">
<ul id="nameList">

</ul>
(Click a list item to see console message)
```

---

References:

- `firstChild` is  inherited from the [`node interface`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)
- `children` is inherited from the [ParentNode mixin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) and is a live HTMLCollection.